# Godot multplayer RPC node tree issues?

Tags: rpc, multiplayer, godot

Hey guys i seem to be having an issue with the RPC API.

I've read that node paths need to be identical and I believe I have achieved this but I'm still having issues?

The server should be able to RPC to the client but it still doesn't work.

```
globals.net_player.set_name(str(get_tree().get_network_unique_id()))
globals.net_player.set_network_master(get_tree().get_network_unique_id())



add_child(globals.net_other_player)
add_child(globals.net_player)
```

[image: RPC Issue #1]

Comment: using rpc_config("set_card", 1) still doesnt work

Comment: scene trees are the same as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rpc() call needs to come from the same location as the rpc it is targeting.

```
extends Node2D
slave func set_name(name):

    pass

func set_name_rpc(name):
    rpc("set_name", name)
    pass
```